# d3- Color gradient fill based on Temperature

Tags: d3.js, colors

I am looking to create a color gradient along the x axis of a d3 chart as the fill-area under the chart, and I'm not sure where to start. Hoping you can help:)

So for example, I draw a line graph based on dates and values.(x and y). Then underneath the line, I want the color of the fill to reflect the temperature for that day (higher temperatures, warmer colors, etc).

```
data = [
    {"date": "2018-04-10"
     "value": "122"
     "temperature" "13"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-11"
     "value": "129"
     "temperature" "15"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-12"
     "value": "114"
     "temperature" "17"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-13"
     "value": "120"
     "temperature" "14"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-14"
     "value": "139"
     "temperature" "11"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-15"
     "value": "120"
     "temperature" "10"
    },
    {"date": "2018-04-16"
     "value": "119"
     "temperature" "13"
    }     
   ]
```

and say my colors are

```
colors = ["red","orange","yellow","green","blue","purple" ]
```

I'm thinking I'd set the area and fill it with a function that will create the color vertically based on the temperature?

```
  var area = d3.svg.area()
.x(function(d, i) { return x(format.parse(d.date)); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

  graph.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("class", "area")
.attr('fill', areaFill)
.attr("d", area);
```

I got this code from [THIS](https://codepen.io/pattmorter/pen/KpOrRj) codepen to get me started... it's obviously not right but helps show how to create a single color fill. So, how might I loop through colors and assign a gradient fill based off a separate value?

Thanks so much for your help! Let me know if I can clarify